# How to filter a list on SharePoint

Tags: list, publishing-site, list-view, filter

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, and I am using Publishing Portal Template. I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5. I have defined a custom list manually on a SharePoint site (all column types of the custom list are SharePoint built-in types), and I want to define some customized rules to filter this list to display only a part of the list. Any reference code?

EDIT1:

Here is my current code. I have used such code to retrieved the items I need, but how to display the retrieved items in a SharePoint list?

```
            SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPList oList = oSiteCollection.AllWebs[0].Lists["PeopleTest"];
            SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
            oQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Department'/>" +
                    "<Value Type='Text'>Computer</Value></Eq></Where>";
            SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.GetItems(oQuery);

            foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
            {
                writer.Write(oListItem["Department"].ToString()+"###");
            }
```

Comment: Wouldn't a normal SharePoint View satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I have updated my reply in EDIT1 section. The built-in filters and views are not enough for my complex application specific logics. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a view (either manually or programmatically), and then get a reference to this SPView, and call [RenderAsHtml()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.renderashtml.aspx) on it. This renders like an SPGridView (which is what you want).

Alternatively, you could use an [SPDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spdatasource.aspx). You can then bind this SPDataSource to an [SPGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx). This can be done declaratively with ASPX/ASCX markup only.

Let me guess, you want a code snippet? :)

Comment: Cool, question answered!

Answer (score 0):

Your filter looks pretty straightforward, but I would go with a Data View Web Part (DVWP).  No back end code, and easily configurable to do what you're showing just using the dialogs.

M.